# Strange behaviour with php datetime objects- subtracting from date a second time when calling diff()

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

When I subtract 1 day from a datetime object, it does as it is supposed to, it subtracts one day. but if I use diff() to compare 2 datetime objects it then subtracts the day again. You can see in the following code example:

```
$currTime = new DateTime();
$lastPurge = new DateTime("14:33");
$lastPurge->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));

echo $lastPurge->format("d/m/Y H:i:s\n\n");

$diff = $currTime->diff($lastPurge);

echo $lastPurge->format("d/m/Y H:i:s\n\n");
```

The output from that code is:

> 10/11/2010 14:33:00
>
> 09/11/2010 14:33:00

As you can see, after calling sub() it has subtracted 1 day, as expected. But then after using diff() it subtracts another day. Why is another day subtracted after using diff() to calculate the difference? Is it supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce on PHP 5.3.3, with America/New_York time zone:

```
php > $currTime = new DateTime();
php > $lastPurge = new DateTime("14:33");
php > $lastPurge->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
php >
php > echo $lastPurge->format("d/m/Y H:i:s\n\n");
09/11/2010 14:33:00

php >
php > $diff = $currTime->diff($lastPurge);
php >
php > echo $lastPurge->format("d/m/Y H:i:s\n\n");
09/11/2010 14:33:00
```

You are right that `diff` says nothing about modifying either input parameter.

EDIT: This is [bug 49059](http://bugs.php.net/49059).  The [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) says the first release with the fix is 5.3.3.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in the PHP versions I am using. I have tried it in php 5.3.1 on Windows with Australia/Broken_Hill timezone and PHP 5.3.2 on Mac OS X (same time zone). I will try building the latest php version and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks! Building the latest php version now. I guess it pays to stay on top of releases.